# Problems with building realm-java library in Android-Studio

Tags: android, cmake, realm

Recently I've tried to build my own realm-java library with help of https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/README.md, but failed on step:

```
Install CMake from SDK manager in Android Studio ("SDK Tools" -> "CMake").
```

There is no (longer ?) CMake plugin in SDK Tools, and to tell the truth I don't know if normal CMake (I have one installed) is able to handle build itself since I found information that CMake which used to be in android-sdk have some additional parameters. Anyone maybe had found a solution to this issue ?

Comment: It's there for me. What version android studio? What version build tools?

Comment: Android Studio 2.1.3 | SDK tools 25.1.7 | SDK build tools 24.0.2  I can only see NDK there (both linux/windows)

Comment: Only NDK? I have like 20 options under SDK tools :/

Comment: I mean only option that is "near valid" (NDK is a bit connected with CMake) ;) I also have about 20 options, but neither me or my work colleagues can't find anything that has "CMake" in name. I suspect that there are some server issues with android SDK in my country (Poland) because I am certain that I saw cmake there also some time ago, that would explain why you can see it. Is package for cmake you see straight named "cmake" or has some additional words ?

Comment: CMake, it is the second option from top

Comment: Uh, try Android Studio 2.2 beta2.